# When does the buffer flush

Tags: c++, buffer, cout, flush

For cpp, I know that we have three cases to flush the buffer:

1. When we get `std::cin`
2. When we `std::cout<<std::endl` (or ohters things like `endl`)
3. When we call some function like `fflush`

If I am right, there is a question:
If I just write `std::cout<<"hello world";` in `main` and run it, I could see "hello world" at the console. So, by whom and when does the buffer flush? By the compiler? Or the buffer will flush when the main finishes?

Comment: And when the buffer fills up or program exits.

Comment: And when the streams destructor is called.

Comment: buffer should flush before program exit.

Comment: @ivanw  are u sure about that?

Comment: Yes, program has to release memory back to the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to read about `std::unitbuf` and `std::nounitbuf`. Here's a decent [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf).

It might be helpful to play with some simple examples. For instance, the following code will not print `Hello world` ever, because there won't be automatic flushing of the output stream after any output operation:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    // ----- Don't want automatic flushing ------
    std::cout << std::nounitbuf;
    std::cout << "Hello world";

    while (1)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

And this code example will indeed print `Hello world`, because I specified that I want the automatic flushing to be enabled:

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    // ----- I do want automatic flushing ------
    std::cout << std::unitbuf;
    std::cout << "Hello world";

    while (1)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

I know that the infiite `while` loop looks a bit silly, but it's the easiest and most portable way of pausing the code that I can think of right now (I'm sure there are better ways, though!). This way I don't get flushing because of (1) code termination, (2) destructors being called and (3) so on. It's all down to the properties of `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbling on the same question, I made a little test

```c
int main() {
    printf("t");
    // fflush(stdout);
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

It appears that without the `fflush`, nothing is printed out.
With the flush, my little "t" appears on the console.

So, adding to the previous response, I believe flushing doesn't happen magically, but with the help of various "events", for example when the program exits, or when the buffer is full.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39536463/8165144) helped me a lot understand it.