# Can't get integer input in c

Tags: c, input, int, scanf

I seriously don't know what is wrong. It may be something very simple, but I can't find the error. I wrote this very simple program in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n%d", &n);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I ran it, this is what I got:

```
1  // My input

-1936471972
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `printf("\n%d", &n)` <=== should be `n`, not `&n`

Comment: You are printing the location of the variable `n`, not its value.

Comment: And it more usual to place the `newline` at the *end* of the format string, like `printf("%d\n", n);` This will pay off big time when you use `printf` for debugging cues.

Comment: @machine_1 was it really so confusing? We usually let minor language slips pass in this multinational community, apart from *programming* typos.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just post what the others have already pointed out:

```
int main(void) {

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
              ^^  ^ 
    return 0;
}
```

Remove the `&` from `&n` if you just want to display the value of the variable *(you were basically printing the address of the variable)* and move the `\n` after you have printed the variable as explained by [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane).

Comment: To enlarge on my above comment: the output through `stdout` is usually buffered, and that buffer is sent to the output device when a `newline` is sent. So if you are printing cues about the state of your program which lack the final `newline`, and your program crashes, the previous output may still be in the buffer, and not actually sent to the device. This can make the debugging cues misleading or useless. It's just good practice to put the `newline` last. But if there are circumstances when you do not *want* a `newline` you can use `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: @Weather Vane Use `stdout()` for certainty.  A `'\n'` [might not flush the output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359).

Answer (score 1):

> I seriously don't know what is wrong.

`printf("\n%d", &n);` use a print specifier of `"%d"`, which expects an `int`.  `&n` is the *address* of an `int`.  What is really good about this is the modern compilers and compilers with their warnings well enable, **will automatically warn about this error**.  This saves you time!  No need for an SO post.

Proficient coders uses tools like a compiler with is warnings well enabled to be efficient and focus on the subtle problems a compilers cannot detect.  Using `printf("\n%d", n);` or `printf("%d\n", n);` may solve today's small problem, but using a better compiler environment is really the thing to learn from all this.

Answer (score 0):

Use that

```
printf("%d\n", n);
```

instead of

```
printf("\n%d", &n);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` takes a variable address as a parameter, but`printf` takes the variable value. Try changing the line to

```
printf("\n%d", n);
```