# Skipping lines of code in C i/o

Tags: c, function, input, output

When learning C in simple programs it often happens that the computer skips the execution of some lines of code, and I can't understand why this is so.

Now as an example, I sketched a program which simply stores 3 numbers entered by the user:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int a, b, c;

printf("Please type in number a: \n");
scanf("%i", &a);
printf("Please type in number c: \n");
scanf("%i", &c);
printf("Please type in number b: \n");
scanf("%i", &b);    
return 0;
}
```

I want to enter 1, 2, and 3. This is what I get in the console (in Ubuntu):

```
Please type in number a:
1
Please type in number b:
Please type in number c:
2
```

The input of number b was ignored.

Not only the second input is skipped, so even the input is in the wrong order. Initially, I wrote everything in alphabetic order in the code - a, b and c, then the input of b was skipped, and then I changed the order in the code and still, as you can see, the execution remained unchanged.

And such cases I have had earlier.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try using %d instead of %i

Comment: When you press Enter, a character is written to stdin.

Comment: @Meccano doesn't work

Comment: Try  `scanf("%i%*c", &a);` (for all)  as `%*c` would read `'\n'` from stdin and discard it.

Comment: @ameyCU doesn't work

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln  It does as I see . Example [here](https://ideone.com/NoriMp).

Comment: @ameyCU I tried this and I also added `printf("%i %i %i\n", a, b, c);` before `return`. Printf was ignored by the program.

Comment: Idea: 1) Code you are compiling and code you are running is not the same. 2) Compiler/option are faulty.  3) Post _exactly_ the keys used as input like `1`, `<Enter>`,`2`, `<Enter>`,`3`, `<Enter>`  4) Printf the return value of each `scanf()`.  `int y = scanf("%i", &a); printf("y:%d\n", a);`

Comment: What compiler are you using. I tried your code on Cygwin and it works fine?

Comment: It could be as simple as the code you edit is not properly saved and _successfully_ compiled before running the executable - IOWs you are running the old code.

Comment: The code shown inputs a, c, b in that order; the sample run claims to input them in the conventional order a, b, c.  There's a mismatch between what you show.

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln Are you compiling your code after you make the edits? Seems like you are only saving and running the old binary.

Answer (score 0):

On 2nd thought, I think OP has another issue

Leaving below as community wiki as a reference

---

To insure output occurs before `scanf()`, flush the output.

```
printf("Please type in number a: \n");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%i", &a);

printf("Please type in number c: \n");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%i", &c);
```

See [What are the rules of automatic flushing stdout buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359)

Comment: I tried `fflush` and the result remains the same I described in the question.