# How to make fprintf() writes immediately

Tags: c

One way to write into a file is by using `fprintf()`. However, this function does not write the results into a file **immediately**. It rather seems to write everything at once when the program is terminated or finished.

My question is the following: I have a program that takes very long time to run (4-5 hours for big dataset). During this time, I want to see the intermediate results so that I don't have to wait for 5 hours. My university uses `Sun Grid Engine` for job submission. As most of you know, you have to wait until your job finishes to see your final results. Thus, I want to be able to write the intermediate results into a text file and see the updated results as the program is processing (Similarly if I am using `printf`).

How can I modify `fprintf()` to write anything I want **immediately** to the target file?

Comment: Use the `fflush` function

Comment: @M.M Haven't seen this function before. Thanks you so much

Comment: See also [What are the rules of automatic flushing stdout buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `fflush` function after each write to flush the output buffer to disk.

```
fprintf(fileptr, "writing to file\n");
fflush(fileptr);
```

If you're on a POSIX system (i.e. Linux, BSD, etc), and you **really** want to be sure the file is written to disk, i.e. you want to flush the kernel buffers as well as the userspace buffers, also use `fsync`:

```
fsync(fileno(fileptr));
```

But `fflush` should be sufficient.  Don't bother with `fsync` unless you find that you need to.

Comment: Really! that simple!!

Comment: Thank you very much. Well explained.

Comment: Isn't `fsync` only for POSIX?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can set FILE pointer _IONBF mode. Then you cloud not use fflush or fsync.
FILE *pFilePointor = fopen(...);
setvbuf(pFilePointor, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

fprintf(...)
fprintf(...)

Answer (score 0):

***fflush***

This works on FILE *. For your case it looks more appropriate. Please note fflush(NULL) will update all opened files / streams and my be CPU intensive. You may like to use/avoid fflush(NULL) for performance reason.

***fsync***

This works on int descriptor. It not only updates file/stream, also metadata. It can work even in system crash / reboot cases as well. You can check man page for more details.

Personally I use **fflush**, and it works fine for me (in Ubuntu / Linux).