# Cant write to Windows pipe via stdout

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, pipe, stdio

`_open_osfhandle` creates a C file descriptor from a windows file handle, and `_dup` can change an existing fd's underlying file object. When used to redirect `stdout` to a `CreatePipe` pipe `ReadFile` does not capture output written to `stdout`.

The following code snippet demonstrates the core of what I am attempting.
I want to create an anonymous pipe, replacing `stdout` so that I can read it from the read handle.

The documentation i've been able to find indicates that `_open_osfhandle`  and `_dup2` can perform this trickery and Microsofts documentation page for [dup2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syseb29.aspx) specifically calls out replacing the fd in stdout as being possible.

Given all that, I am expecting the following code to return immediately from ReadFile with the bytes written by printf as prior calls to `_write` and `fprintf` worked as expected.

```
HANDLE hread;
HANDLE hwrite;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa),NULL,TRUE };
CreatePipe(&hread, &hwrite, &sa, 0);
int fd = _open_osfhandle(intptr_t(hwrite), _O_TEXT);
FILE *fp = _fdopen(fd, "w");
setvbuf(fp, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
_dup2(_fileno(fp), _fileno(stdout));
TCHAR buffer[64] = { 0 };
DWORD bytesRead;
//_write(fd, "_write", 6); // works
//fprintf(fp, "fprintf"); // works
printf("printf");
ReadFile(hread, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL);
```

Comment: in what question ? possible `fprintf` cache data in internal buffer and not call `WriteFile`. until you not flush buffer will be no data in pipe. call `fflush` after fprintf

Comment: That was the problem I was having. until I figured out `setvbuf`. The ultimate goal was using _dup2 to replace the fd in stdout. but that still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Investigation has finally yielded fruit. The file stream opened by _fdopen is buffered by default preventing anything actually being written to the underlying OS pipe handle. `setvbuf` can be used to turn that off so writes happen immediately.

Performing a `dup2` to reset the underlying file bound to stdout's file descriptor resets the buffering, so the following code works. The call to `_fdopen` is dropped as not needed and the `setvbuf' is performed on stdout.

```
HANDLE hread;
HANDLE hwrite;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa),NULL,TRUE };
CreatePipe(&hread, &hwrite, &sa, 0);
int fd = _open_osfhandle(intptr_t(hwrite), _O_TEXT);
_dup2(fd, _fileno(stdout));
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
TCHAR buffer[64] = { 0 };
DWORD bytesRead;
printf("printf");
ReadFile(hread, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339874/how-to-make-fprintf-writes-immediately