# Reading EOF from getchar() in C on a windows 10 system

Tags: c

I'm working on character K&R C book to try to learn the C language. I'm having a lot of issues because I'm using windows 10 OS instead of Linux. I'm using msys2 to compile and run my code. I for the longest time couldn't figure out the File copying from section 1.5.1 until asking for help from an expert in the field. He pointed out that I needed to use fflush(stdout);

```
{
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {  // read buffer store in c, then check if it is EOF(ctrl+z on windows)
        fflush(stdout); //flush buffer
        putchar(c);    // print the character retrieved
        printf("%d\n",(c));
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Adding that made my program work as expected. However, Now I'm running into similar difficulty on the character counter of the next section.

```
long counter = 0;  // initialize c variable
while (getchar() != EOF) {  //check if character received is EOF(ctrl+z on windows)
    fflush(stdout); //flush buffer
    ++counter;    // incrementcounter
}
fflush(stdout);
printf("%ld\n",(counter));
return(0);
```

I never see the print on my counter at the end. 
[The attached image shows what happens when I run the file. The "Stopped" print is from when I sent EOF(ctr+Z).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44GwT.png)

I essentially have two questions:

1. What exactly happens when I send EOF to my kernel.
2. Is there a way to send EOF without immediately killing my program?
   I hope that was easy to follow and thank you all in advance.

Comment: You should be calling `fflush(stdout)` _after_ the `printf`, not before it.

Comment: @iBug Only if `stdout` is a console.

Comment: In general , outputting a newline does not cause a flush

Comment: Pressing Ctrl-Z in a unix-like shell (such as you are using) suspends the process. (It does not kill the program as you seem to be assuming). You can resume the process by typing `fg` (short for "foreground" - bring the suspended job to the foreground). To send EOF press Ctrl-D

Comment: @iBug Re: [a trailing newline. It serves as fflush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503441/reading-eof-from-getchar-in-c-on-a-windows-10-system#comment81962722_47503441) `'\n'` is not specified to flush the stream.  [What are the rules of automatic flushing stdout buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359)

Comment: @vburns Be sure to use `int c` for this task and not `char c`.

Comment: @M.M You need to press `C-D` on an empty line to send an EOF. Same for `C-Z`. Interestingly in Windows CMD you need to press `C-Z` the `Enter` for EOF.

Comment: You will definitely want to look at [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Nope. It's MSYS, a Unix shell environment for Windows.

Comment: Then you should be good. It shouldn't matter for msys (though I will have to confirm the next time I boot win10 -- after rolling back the problematic FCU, I don't really have anything to do there now...)

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly happens when i send EOF to my kernel.

The system (MSYS) tells the program that its standard input has reached EOF (end-of-file), and there'll be no more input availablr.

> Is there a way to send EOF without immediately killing my program?

No. Sending an EOF never terminates a program immediately. It lets the program continue without reading input anymore. It's your program that terminates itself when it found nothing to read.

The reason you see `Stopped` is that you didn't send an EOF at all! Oj Unix shells (including MSYS and Cygwin), Ctrl-Z means **Suspend**. You can type `fg` to bring it to foreground again, then press **Ctrl-D** to send it an EOF.

Note: Ctrl-Z sends EOF only in Windows CMD, and in Windows 10 [you have to uncheck a box](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/).

Comment: Note for the Win10 [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/) .. until you check the right box.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OMG. Then how to send EOF without checking that box?

Comment: You can't. Leave it to M$ to forget all about the need to generate an `EOF` from the command line `:(` You can't even generate a `EOF` in the VS Developers Console until you check that box...

Comment: @DavudC.Rankin Thank God I've been using WSL since Windows 10. I'm adapted to Ctrl-D now :)

Comment: @iBug First of all thank you for your answer. So when you said "No. Sending an EOF never terminates a program immediately. It lets the program continue without reading input anymore. It's your program that terminates itself when it found nothing to read." I don't understand why program killed itself before seeing the printf("%ld\n",(counter));. It should've stayed up until we return correct?