# Why does printf() with \n still not flush on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, mingw-w64, flush, msys2

My Windows program (compiled using MSYS2 MINGW64) outputs its `stdout` data in large blocks. A `printf()` call with a `\n` doesn't correctly flush the output.

As a variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin), **under what conditions does `printf()` NOT flush?**

---

As an example, the following code outputs in blocks on MSYS2 MINGW64:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        while(1) {
                printf("test\n");
                Sleep(1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201325/10805404), it does not flush when encountering a newline (aka *line buffered*) if `stdout` is *fully buffered* (this is the case if it is not an interactive device, it could be a file for example). Also, this has actually nothing to to with `printf` but only with the stream.

Comment: Windows stdio doesn't do line buffering for output streams.

Comment: @Xunie: it's not language-lawyering because it's not about the language. It's completely dependent on the execution environment (OS/shell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows there's no line buffering, only no and full buffering

> - `_IOLBF`
>
>   - For some systems, this provides line buffering. However, for Win32, the behavior is the same as `_IOFBF` - Full Buffering.
>
> [setvbuf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setvbuf?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019)

Wait for a while until the buffer is full, or flush the buffer yourself. Alternatively you can decrease the buffer size with `setvbuf()` so that it flushes more frequently

Answer (score 3):

It appears that in the msys2 shell running under mintty, at least for MINGW64, *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* all report 0 (false) for `isatty()`, whereas if you open a Windows CMD.EXE prompt and run the same executable, all three file descriptors (0, 1, and 2) return 1 (true).

I'm not convinced this has always been the behavior, as I'm pretty sure I never ran into this until I re-installed msys2.

This is not the correct behavior according to POSIX.1 [IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 (Revision of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008)], https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

> At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and need not be opened explicitly: standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output). When opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

My tests indicate that neither stdout nor stdin *not* fully buffered when running the msys2 bash shell in mintty.

Adding the following to the beginning of your `main()` does make stderr and stdout non-buffered:

```
(void)setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
(void)setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Comment: Another option is to use the new "Windows Terminal", which is pretty decent.
See https://www.msys2.org/docs/terminals/

Answer (score 2):

> under what conditions does `printf()` NOT flush?

With *mingw-w64*, I am not aware, yet the behavior of *mingw-w64* is not required to apply elsewhere.  Code cautiously is only targeting one implementation.

The following applies to C, in general.

Typically if the `printf()` lacks a `'\n'`, it does not flush, yet that is  *implementation defined* behavior.

The conditions in which `printf()` flushes or does not is *implementation defined*.  There are many possibilities.  See [What are the rules of automatic stdout buffer flushing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359)

To insure `stdout` is *flushed*, follow with a `fflush(stdout);`.

Answer (score -1):

As an addition to the other answer you can do all your output in `printf` just don't do the `\n` and instead use `cout << endl` after it. That oughta flush the output.

Comment: `cout << endl` sounds like a good idea for another language, but not `C` as this post is tagged.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought it was C++. You can use fflush(stdin) instead of endl I think.

Comment: Re: [can use fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426558/why-does-printf-with-n-still-not-flush/61434960?noredirect=1#comment108677071_61434960), Suggest reviewing [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/2410359)