# Scanf executed before printf in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, printing, ide, scanf

I have the following simple code in C language:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Give an integer:\n");
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("10*%d=%d\n",x,10*x);

    return 0;
}
```

Using **CodeBlocks IDE** it is executed in the right order but when I use **Eclipse IDE** it jumps 
to the scanf command and then prints the messages as it should. Can anyone explain this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: maybe one environment sets `stdout` to *fully buffered* rather than the usual *line buffered*. Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after `printf()` calls to force outputs.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. In the CodeBlocks IDE nothing changed, as I wanted, and in the Eclipse it works as i wanted.

Comment: Alternatively, see if you can prevent the IDE to set `stdout` to *fully buffered*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually `stdout` is set to *line buffered*. Apparently one of your IDEs sets it to *fully buffered*.

You can force prints to dump the associated buffer with `fflush()`, eg

```
printf("hello ");   // works in unbuffered stream
printf("world!\n"); // works in line buffered stream
fflush(stdout);     // works in fully buffered stream
```