# How to run C programs in Git bash?

Tags: c, git-bash

I'm on Windows and I'm using git bash to run my c program.

I use gcc to compile the code. When I just do a simple `printf("hello, world");` it works, but when I try to create a simple program that adds two numbers it just does nothing.

It compiles with `gcc -o sum sum.c` but when I run it using `./sum` it does nothing, but when I run it in my command prompt it runs normally.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n1, n2;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("Enter another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);

    int sum = n1 + n2;

    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
}
```

[image]
I tried Entering values in the git bash and got this output compared to cmd

Comment: So it produces the expected output in the Windows Command Prompt but none in Git Bash? It might be to do with flushing then.

Comment: I'd like to support this question, Git bash accepts two inputs `a` and `b` first and then prints all the `printf()` statements but everything's working fine in Command Prompt and PowerShell.

Comment: I added screenshots of how I ran sum.c in both cmd and git bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this problem fixed by appending `fflush(stdout)` after those `printf()` statements:

```
printf("Enter first value: ");
fflush(stdout); // this
scanf("%d", &a);

printf("Enter second value: ");
fflush(stdout); // this
scanf("%d", &b);
```

Just flushing the buffer will let the program wait for your input after printing.

**The working example screenshot:**

[image: Git Bash Working Program Example]

Comment: It works to me too but can you explain. What does `fflush(stdout)` actually do here. And why does it work normally in cmd without the use of `fflush(stdout)`

Comment: [What are the rules of automatic stdout buffer flushing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39536803/11471113) thread might be helpful for you in this case.

Comment: @RohanBari it's still strange that the same binary has different behaviour depending on the shell it is run from.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Change from null to Git Bash, on VSCode Settings.