# Interactive stdin, stdout with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdout, stdin

I've read some discussions about this but I couldn't find anything on how to correct the error I have.

I have a C program, for a device, that is interactive, user input gives out hardware status, measurement, etc. The program returns the asked data. Initialization takes a few seconds so I can't afford to re-run the program each time I want a measurement, as some sub-routine needs a few thousand samples a second. I want my data to be exported into python somehow to make all my calculations and graph displays. I could adapt the C program but I'd rather change the python script to accommodate for it.

For testing purposes I have this simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int command;
    printf("Line1\n");
    printf("Line2\n");

    while(1){
        scanf("%d", &command);
        if (command == 0) break;
        else if (command == 1) printf("result : s_0 = 1, s_1 = 0.05, s_0 = 0.5, s_0 = -0.85\n");
        else printf("Unknown\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I have tried to run it inside a subprocess and use the stdin, stdout as `communicate()` ends the communication afterward :

```
import subprocess as sp
from subprocess import PIPE
import time

p = sp.Popen(["a.exe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

# p.stdin.write(b'1\n') # Blocks here
print(p.stdout.readlines()) # Here too
p.stdout.flush()
p.stdin.write(b'0\n')
p.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(0.1)

print(p.stdout.readlines())

if not p.poll():p.kill()
```

I tried a lot of things from what I've seen over my research. Should I use a queue or a thread ? Why am I not getting anything out, it looks like I got deadlock since the first time I try to either write or read the pipe first. Python froze (not responsive to Ctrl+C but my keys are still put in the buffer as they appear after python is killed) and I have to kill the Python process each time.

Is there something better to accommodate for my case?

**EDIT**

As I don't want to create a new post that is similar I post my new, related issue, here.
I implemented @Paul Cornelius solution and it worked. Hence I tried to make a command input to make the command transit throw python and go into the C program process :

```
p = sp.Popen(["a.exe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

print("Line 1", p.stdout.readline())
print("Line 2", p.stdout.readline())

while(True):
    command = input("Command > ")
    p.stdin.write((command + '\n').encode())
    p.stdin.flush()
    if command == '0':
        break
    print("Answer : ", p.stdout.readline())

if not p.poll():
    p.kill()
```

I have one issue (maybe more but I can't know) and a question.

The first two lines appear, no issue here, but once I reach the `input` I can't type anything, I'd like to know if that is normal and what is the fix.

I changed the C program like @Paul Cornelius made it with the flush of the stdout buffer.

My question is about the first two Line, I tried using `p.stdout.readlines()` instead of `p.stdout.readline()` twice but it didn't work (freeze like in my original question). Why doesn't it work here but work at the end of the script? EOF character?

Answer (score 1):

C programs buffer stdout.  So you need to flush stdout after each write or else the Python program won't see anything:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int command;
    printf("Line1\n");
    printf("Line2\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    while(1){
        scanf("%d", &command);
        if (command == 0) break;
        else if (command == 1) printf("result : s_0 = 1, s_1 = 0.05, s_0 = 0.5, s_0 = -0.85\n");
        else printf("Unknown\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the Python program I rearranged a few things to get a better match to your C program logic.  (Perhaps some of it was unnecessary.)  The calls to p.stdin.flush are required.  This program works:

```
import subprocess as sp
from subprocess import PIPE
import time

p = sp.Popen([r"c:\gcc64proj\so\so1.exe"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)

print("Line 1", p.stdout.readline())
print("Line 2", p.stdout.readline())
p.stdin.write(b'1\n')
p.stdin.flush()
print("Line 3", p.stdout.readline())
p.stdin.write(b'2\n')
p.stdin.write(b'0\n')
p.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(0.1)

print(p.stdout.readlines())

if not p.poll():
    p.kill()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, on my first test I forgot the first fflush that you added before the scanf so it didn't work but now it's good ! Could you maybe explain to me why I need to flush I thought it was done automatically once I try to write a \n within stdout?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536212/what-are-the-rules-of-automatic-stdout-buffer-flushing-in-c