# reasons why pipe buffering not working correctly

Tags: c, linux, pipe, io-buffering

I countered something that really irritate me while running this code on https://cpp.sh/

```
// taken from here https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, fgets */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* atoi */

int main ()
{
  //* setbuf(stdout, NULL);
  int i;
  char buffer[256];
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  fgets (buffer, 256, stdin);
  i = atoi (buffer);
  printf ("The value entered is %d. Its double is %d.\n",i,i*2);
  return 0;
}
```

it shows the next output (entered "10\n" as input):

```
10 
Enter a number: The value entered is 10. Its double is 20.
```

I am familiar with the concept of linux pipes and buffering, and I know that the pip flush the content of stdout before listening to input, so I wonderd why fgets don't flush stdout before waiting to input.

when removing the comment from the line with * it works as expected, and while compile and run with gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0 also works, so I don't understand whats going on when I run it on the online c++ compiler?

Comment: What does any of this have to do with pipes?

Comment: because it works when I set the stdout to be unbuffers, and the buffers sit in the pipe. am I wrong?

Comment: I do not understand. Why would you expect `fgets(... stdin)` to do _anything_ with `stdout`? There is however a "special case" in glibc https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/af16a59ee1f72392b88d439d8f802c9844f86f4f/libio/fileops.c#L491 , but I do not  know if it is relevant.

Comment: No, the buffer is in stdio.

Comment: If this were the pipe's buffer, how would `setbuf()` change it? That just controls stdio buffering.

Comment: but setbuf getting a stream as parameter so why it can't interfere with stdout buffering?

Comment: @KamilCuk according to [online c 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)
7.21.3 Files
When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment

Comment: stdin and stdout are different streams. One is stdin, the other is stdout.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "and I know that the pip flush the content of stdout before listening to input".  Do you mean that you believe that the call to `fgets` will flush stdout?  That's simply not true.  If you want to flush stdout, you should call `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: why not? [couldn't find something more formal fast his assumptions are wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536212/what-are-the-rules-of-automatic-stdout-buffer-flushing-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `stdout` is fully buffered unless it's connected to a terminal; in that case it's line-buffered. The prompt won't be printed until the output buffer fills up, which is likely to be 4K bytes.

You can call `fflush(stdout)` to force the buffer to be written to the pipe.

```
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

Comment: interesting but I don't understand why the stdout stream open as fully buffered to begin with, according to [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)  "the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive devic"

Comment: I think the `cpp.sh` website is using a pipe, not a terminal.

Comment: make sense thanks, if you could also reflect about my understanding in buffering because I started to be confused, each file descriptor have its own buffer and I can create a pipe from one file descriptor to another that will contain 16 buffers that will act like one? and it lays in kernel mode right, if I am not in the right path I would love to get any sources to wrap my head around it

Comment: There are lots of different buffers at different levels. The buffers you're concerned with are in `FILE` objects managed by stdio, not file descriptors or pipes.

Comment: @nadavlevin: pipes are not interactive devices, so when stdout is associated with a pipe, it will be fully buffered.  On linux (and unix systems in general), "interactive device" and "terminal" mean the same thing.